# Can I test for a significant difference within one variable?

Tags: t-test, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, differences

I collected microplastics falling on an island in a year. The types of microplastics are fiber (F) and miscellaneous (M) particles. I want to know if the number of each that fell are significantly different.

I collected at two sites but I want to combine these sites together for the island as a whole.

The percentages of fibers that fell (after combining sites) are 72% fibers and 28% miscellaneous. A lot more fibers were collected than miscellaneous, but I want a p-value to see if it is a significant difference. Is this possible?

I labeled each particle as either an "F" or "M". I was trying to use a chi-squared test in R because I am using categorical variables but it doesn't seem to be working. I was trying to compare an x value of "F" against y value of "M".

I ended up creating this table, with a "1" denoting present and "0" denoting absent.

| Sample | F | M |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Sample 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Sample 3 | 1 | 0 |

chisq.test(table$F, table$M)

But this gave me a p-value of < 2.2e-16. I replicated this in two other data sets and I got the same p-value so I know that this value is not correctly analyzing my data.

I'm running around in circles and not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Why do you think that you need a p-value? Why would it make sense to suppose that fibres and miscellaneous particles each make up 50% of the 'population' of microplastics? If there are far more fibres than miscellaneous particles then that is your answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to *quantify* what you found rather than testing that particular hypothesis?  What difference would it make, scientifically or practically or in any other meaningful sense, between concluding there's a significant difference and not concluding there's a significant difference between the fiber and miscellaneous proportions?

Comment: @MichaelLew Doesn't a p-value tell me if a difference is perhaps by chance or not? If the difference in fibers falling more often than miscellaneous particles are due to chance or not...Are you saying that a p-value won't help me? I know you're trying to help but answering my question with another question doesn't help me.

Comment: @whuber See above if that helps. Fibers often show up more in atmospheric studies than miscellaneous. By showing that the difference is significant, then it didn't happen by chance. Maybe the difference isn't actually meaningful and I may not include the p-value in my study. But it would still be interesting to figure out how to perform this stats. My question is how? Is it even possible? Usually chi-squared you have two variables to compare to. I'm trying to compare within one population of Fibers vs Misc. Not sure that I can even statistically test in this way.

Comment: The "chance" mechanism scarcely seems implied by theory or relevant to questions of importance, because all it says is that "fibers have a 50% chance of appearing."  What we are wondering is why answering such a specific question would be more meaningful than answering questions like "is the chance of a fiber appearing equal to 39.378%?"

Comment: A p-value does not tell you that the thing did or did not "happen by chance". It tells you how surprising or unusual the observation is according to the statistical model with the hypothesis parameter set to the 'null' value. Your problem is that there is no obvious statistical model and no obvious 'null' value for the proportions. Why would you hypothesise that the number of fibres and non-fibres be equal? If you later decided that one of the plastic types among the 'miscellaneous' was an interesting subset would you hypothesise 33% for fibres, miscellaneous, and the new subset? Not likely.

Comment: I think that you would be best served by simply putting a confidence interval around each proportion and reporting them. If you need help with that then ask a new question.